# Volumetric Light Shading in Three.js with Additive Blending

Tags: javascript, three.js, shader

Hello everyone and thanks for spending some time to read this;

I'm trying to implement a model of the Solar System in three.js. In order to model the Sun, I wanted to implement a volumetric light effect as the one showed [here](https://medium.com/@andrew_b_berg/volumetric-light-scattering-in-three-js-6e1850680a41).
However, as the article uses an older version of three.js, I'm trying to re-implement the code in the newer version.

The described approach is pretty simple:

1. Create two layers on the same scene, one holding the volumetric light and the all-black orbiting object and the other holding the object with the right material
2. Apply the volumetric light shading on the hidden layer
3. Apply an additive blending shader on the top layer, exploiting the texture obtained from the rendering of the hidden layer

I managed to correctly set up the two scenes. However, this is what I get:

[Link to Codepen](https://codepen.io/Gianfry7/pen/xxgqQJr)

[Link to image of result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IWsAZ.png)

```
    import { RenderPass } from 'https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/three@0.127.0/examples/jsm/postprocessing/RenderPass.js';
    import { ShaderPass } from 'https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/three@0.127.0/examples/jsm/postprocessing/ShaderPass.js';
    import { EffectComposer } from 'https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/three@0.127.0/examples/jsm/postprocessing/EffectComposer.js';
    
    THREE.VolumetericLightShader = {
        uniforms: {
          tDiffuse: {value:null},
          lightPosition: {value: new THREE.Vector2(0.5, 0.5)},
          exposure: {value: 0.18},
          decay: {value: 0.95},
          density: {value: 0.8},
          weight: {value: 0.4},
          samples: {value: 50}
        },
      
        vertexShader: [
          "varying vec2 vUv;",
          "void main() {",
            "vUv = uv;",
            "gl_Position = projectionMatrix * modelViewMatrix * vec4( position, 1.0 );",
          "}"
        ].join("\n"),
      
        fragmentShader: [
          "varying vec2 vUv;",
          "uniform sampler2D tDiffuse;",
          "uniform vec2 lightPosition;",
          "uniform float exposure;",
          "uniform float decay;",
          "uniform float density;",
          "uniform float weight;",
          "uniform int samples;",
          "const int MAX_SAMPLES = 100;",
          "void main()",
          "{",
            "vec2 texCoord = vUv;",
            "vec2 deltaTextCoord = texCoord - lightPosition;",
            "deltaTextCoord *= 1.0 / float(samples) * density;",
            "vec4 color = texture2D(tDiffuse, texCoord);",
            "float illuminationDecay = 1.0;",
            "for(int i=0; i < MAX_SAMPLES; i++)",
            "{",
              "if(i == samples){",
                "break;",
              "}",
              "texCoord -= deltaTextCoord;",
              "vec4 SSS = texture2D(tDiffuse, texCoord);",
              "SSS *= illuminationDecay * weight;",
              "color += SSS;",
              "illuminationDecay *= decay;",
            "}",
            "gl_FragColor = color * exposure;",
          "}"
        ].join("\n")
      };
      
      THREE.AdditiveBlendingShader = {
        uniforms: {
          tDiffuse: { value:null },
          tAdd: { value:null }
        },
      
        vertexShader: [
          "varying vec2 vUv;",
          "void main() {",
            "vUv = uv;",
            "gl_Position = projectionMatrix * modelViewMatrix * vec4( position, 1.0 );",
          "}"
        ].join("\n"),
      
        fragmentShader: [
          "uniform sampler2D tDiffuse;",
          "uniform sampler2D tAdd;",
          "varying vec2 vUv;",
          "void main() {",
            "vec4 color = texture2D( tDiffuse, vUv );",
            "vec4 add = texture2D( tAdd, vUv );",
            "gl_FragColor = color + add;",
          "}"
        ].join("\n")
      };
      
      
    
    
    // RENDERER
    const renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
    const DEFAULT_LAYER = 0;
    const OCCLUSION_LAYER = 1;
    renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
      document.body.appendChild( renderer.domElement );
    
    // MAIN SCENE
    var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(75, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 0.1, 1000);
    camera.position.z = 6;
    var scene = new THREE.Scene();
    scene.add(new THREE.AmbientLight(0xffffff));
    var pointLight = new THREE.PointLight(0xffffff);
    pointLight.position.set(0, 0, 0);
    scene.add(pointLight);
    
    
    // OCCLUSION SCENE
    
    // Volumetric light in occlusion scene
    var vlight = new THREE.Mesh(
        new THREE.SphereBufferGeometry(1, 64, 64),
        new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
            color: 0xffffff
        })
    );
    vlight.position.set(0, 0, 0);
    vlight.layers.set(OCCLUSION_LAYER);
    scene.add(vlight);
    
   
    // DEFAULT SCENE
    // orbiting sphere in default scene
    var boxgeom = new THREE.SphereBufferGeometry(0.2, 64, 64);
    var material = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({ color: 0xff5533 });
    var box = new THREE.Mesh(boxgeom, material);
    box.position.z = 2;
    scene.add(box);
    
    // orbiting sphere in occluding scene
    var oclmaterial = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({ color: 0x000000 });
    var oclbox = new THREE.Mesh(boxgeom, oclmaterial);
    oclbox.position.z = 2;
    oclbox.layers.set(OCCLUSION_LAYER);
    scene.add(oclbox);
    
    //renderer.render(scene, camera);
    
    
    // Post-processing - occluding target scene
    
    var renderTargetOcl = new THREE.WebGLRenderTarget(window.innerWidth*0.5, window.innerHeight*0.5);
    var oclcomposer = new EffectComposer(renderer, renderTargetOcl);
    // Add render pass to render the sphere
    var renderModelOcl = new RenderPass(scene, camera);
    oclcomposer.addPass(renderModelOcl);
    // Apply volumetric light shader
    var grPass = new ShaderPass(THREE.VolumetericLightShader);
    grPass.needsSwap = true;
    oclcomposer.addPass(grPass);
    //oclcomposer.render();
    grPass.renderToScreen = false;
    
    
    
    // Post-processing - main scene
    var renderTarget = new THREE.WebGLRenderTarget(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
    var composer = new EffectComposer(renderer, renderTarget);
    // Render the main scene with a renderpass
    var renderModel = new RenderPass(scene, camera);
    composer.addPass(renderModel); // Add rendering
    // Apply additive blending shader
    var addingPass = new ShaderPass(THREE.AdditiveBlendingShader);
    addingPass.renderToScreen = true;
    addingPass.uniforms.tAdd.value = renderTargetOcl.texture;
    composer.addPass(addingPass); // Add additive blending
    
    
    
    function animate() {
        requestAnimationFrame(animate);
        render();
    };
    
    function render() {
        // ... move camera and light as needed
    
        var posnew = new THREE.Vector3().copy(box.position).applyAxisAngle(new THREE.Vector3(0, 1, 0), 0.03);
        box.position.copy(posnew);
        oclbox.position.copy(posnew);
    
        // Render
        camera.layers.set(OCCLUSION_LAYER);
        renderer.setClearColor(0x000000);
        oclcomposer.render();
    
        camera.layers.set(DEFAULT_LAYER);
        renderer.setClearColor(0x090611);
        composer.render();
    
    
        //renderer.render(scene, camera);
    }
    
    animate();
```

It seems that the texture fed to the additive blending shader does not account for the volumetric light post processing effect. However, if I render the two layers separately, commenting the

> oclcomposer.render()

or the

> composer.render()

lines at the end of the code, the effect is correctly displayed:

[Rendering of hidden layer (no composer.render())](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gkGLC.png)

[Rendering of default layer (no oclcomposer.render())](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2Ra3P.png)

I am having trouble debugging this issue; moreover, I'm not confident with 3D coding and hoped that I could just plug-and-play the shader and obtain the desired effect. But now, I'm interested in understanding why the volumetric shader seems not having any effect on the additive blending. Can someone provide some solution or insight?

Answer (score 2):

I managed to get the effect I like with the following procedure:

- Add an additional dummy pass to the hidden layer (a CopyShader pass)
- Instead of reading the image to overlay from the renderTargetOcl.texture, now I read it directly from the oclcomposer writeBuffer, like:

> ```
> addingPass.uniforms.tAdd.value = oclcomposer.writeBuffer;
> ```

However, this does not work if I remove the dummy pass or I switch to the readBuffer. This is strange to me, as:

1. The CopyShader readBuffer should read from the previous pass, so it should already have the volumetric light shading effect
2. The Volumetric Light Shading effect should have, by definition, the effect loaded in its writeBuffer

I won't say that the problem has been solved as I can't give an explanation to this behavior; however, the code works.

Comment: PERFECT! :D
I think I searched now for a couple of days, to solve this.
The CopyShader did it! 
I'm using  
occlusionComposer.renderTarget1.texture;  
AND  
vlPass.needsSwap = true;

Thank You man!

Cheers, Steph